# how to define DN for ldif file if DC is not provided while configuring with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am using embedded ldap server with spring boot for testing my ldif file and its credentials but as I found my ldif file format is bit different than normal ldif as dc is not privided, inside dn only o is given.

I have tried different configuration for the above said ldif format but it is still showing Bad Credentials screen but it is working fine with other ldif files.

ldif file

```
# id=00000001
dn: o=COMPANY
objectClass: organization
structuralObjectClass: organization
o: COMPANY
entryCSN: 20130409162114.626166Z#000000#000#000000
entryUUID: 3e7f8668-357d-1032-8a6b-c5bcf7f703f0
creatorsName: cn=Manager,o=COMPANY
createTimestamp: 20130409162114Z
modifiersName: cn=Manager,o=COMPANY
modifyTimestamp: 20130409162114Z
contextCSN: 20130702105648.506150Z#000000#000#000000
contextCSN: 20191018052018.692119Z#000000#001#000000
contextCSN: 20191018044350.858888Z#000000#002#000000
contextCSN: 20191018053729.621549Z#000000#003#000000

# id=00000002
dn: ou=department,o=COMPANY
objectClass: organizationalUnit
structuralObjectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: department
entryCSN: 20130409162455.623488Z#000000#000#000000
entryUUID: c2390a06-357d-1032-8a6c-c5bcf7f703f0
creatorsName: cn=Manager,o=COMPANY
createTimestamp: 20130409162455Z
modifiersName: cn=Manager,o=COMPANY
modifyTimestamp: 20130409162455Z
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=department")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://localhost:8389/o=COMPANY")
                    .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                    .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn= o=COMPANY
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:ldap-server-2.ldif
spring.ldap.embedded.port= 8389
spring.ldap.embedded.validation.enabled=false
```

After, configuring with all above details, application executes well and I get authentication screen but event after right credentials, I am getting Bad Credentials screen.
I don't what's wrong, whether it is dn name for ldif or what?

Please provide your valuable suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an issue per se to have `o=COMPANY` as the root entry instead of using a DC.

Your ldif seems correct, but what is shown here does not contain any user entry (just `id=00000001` and `id=00000002`).

So, according to `userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=department")`, user entries should be contained in `ou=department` and thus defined *after* in your ldif file, eg. :

```
# id=00000003
dn: uid=test,ou=department,o=COMPANY
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
uid: test
mail: test@domain.com
cn: Firstname Lastname
givenName: Firstname
sn: Lastname
```

Also, most servers don't accept anonymous bindings and the authentication request itself may need to bind to the server in order to search for the given entry and test its credentials, just add `managerDn()` and `managerPassword()` in WebSecurityConfig's `configure` method :

```
.contextSource()
  .url('ldap://localhost:8389/o=COMPANY')
  .managerDn('admin')
  .managerPassword('password')
  .and()
...
```

You can also set these ContextSource params in *application.properties* :

```
spring.ldap.embedded.credential.username= uid=admin
spring.ldap.embedded.credential.password= password
```

Comment: Thank you @Eric I made same mistake as you said, I was not focusing on user data inside ldif file. Now, its working fine. Thanks for the help!